# How to see log of a code signed mac application that does not start?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, app-store

At the end of my build process, I codeSign my .app like that :

```
codeSign -s 3rd Party Mac Developer Application: MyCOmpany myApp.app
```

And after, I package it like that :

```
productbuild --component myApp.app /Applications --sign 3rd Party Mac Developer Installer: myCompany imageName.pkg
```

These steps are working.  After that, I am launching the pkg with the following command :

```
sudo installer -store -pkg imageName.pkg -target /
```

The above command output the following traces :

```
installer: imageName.pkg has valid signature for submission: 3rd Party Mac Developer Installer: myCompany
installer: Installation Check: Passed
installer: Volume Check: Passed
installer: Bundle com.myCompany.appName will be installed to /Applications/appName.app
installer: Starting install
installer: Install 0.0% complete
installer: Install 7.3% complete
installer: Install 14.3% complete
installer: Install 20.5% complete
installer: Install 25.7% complete
installer: Install 32.7% complete
installer: Install 36.3% complete
installer: Install 44.7% complete
installer: Install 100.0% complete
installer: Finished install
```

Everything look good so far.

The problem occurs when I try to start the software.  I have a first popup where I have to enter my tester apple id.  After that, i have the following error :

**myApp is damaged and can't be opened.  Delete myApp and download it again from the App Store.**

**Questions : Where can I get some traces from that?  I am completely blind now, there is no way to know what is going on!**

By the way, if I don't build for the mac store, my app starts properly, so I guess I have a problem with the codeSign...

=========================================

**EDIT :**

So, i didn't know about the Console (i am new on mac).  After some traces outputted from my binary, i got the following line form the mac apple store mechanism :

```
com.apple.launchd.peruser.503:([0x0-0x201201].com.myCompanymyCmpany.myAppName[47223]) Exited with code: 173
storeagent[244] promptResponse: <CKSignInPromptResponse:0x105e24990 returnCode:1
```

Why i get that error?  After a quick [search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984881/cannot-get-mac-app-store-receipt), it looks like that this is a receipt error.  I am not sure yet how to resolve this.

**EDIT :**

THe problem is coming from the code that i inherited.  I realized that we have a routine that validate the receipt.  I had a problem in this routine and the validation check was returning false. That is why the program was not starting..  Initially, no traces was in that piece of code, that is why I didnt realized before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you can check the `system.log` (e.g. using the *Console* application from *Utilities* or by checking `/var/log/system.log`). Alternatively you can try to start the app binary directly from the console (useful if you want to hook `gdb` to it, trace it or something like that).

Comment: I already tried starting from the terminal.  I have some traces coming from my binary, but it stops after few seconds and the Apple Store mechanism is taking the lead.  But i found something from the Console.  See my edit!

Answer (score 0):

Try using Xcode and in the organizer you can see the Ipad / Iphone / Ipod you are connected too if you connect it to the laptop. Then from there you will see the console logs for that device and these should provide you some more information as to what is occurring. This will also provide you with the crash logs also for the device.

Comment: What I want to do, is to try the apple store mechanism, where you have to enter you apple ID to start the application.  XCode is not involved at that point ( I think?).  Moreover, i am testing a Mac application.